# Rake db:migrate uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

In order to run rake db:migrate I need both my models and constants defined in application controller.

When I run it I get this

```
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

uninitialized constant Secondsperday
```

All I need is rake to load the environment. It used to do this...

```
Secondsperday is not a model, its this line in application controller.rb

Secondsperday = 24 * 3_600
```

Please help, I've been stuck for a week.

Answer (score 2):

Migrations don't load application controller.

If you want application-wide constants define them in a file placed in $RAILS_ROOT/config/initializers

Comment: seriously, didn't they used to?

Comment: Also, I need my models - I need the whole environment, really.